# Fixture breaking after service override

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, phpunit, silverstripe, fixtures

This test was run with PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann on Silverstripe 3.4.0

**OverrideTest.yml**

```
ExtMember:
  ext_member:
    Email: ext@email.com
    Password: extpassword
```

**OverrideTest.php**

```
class ExtMember extends Member {}

class OverrideTest extends SapphireTest
{
    protected static $fixture_file = 'OverrideTest.yml';

    public function testBrokenFixtures()
    {
        $MockExtMember = $this->getMockBuilder('ExtMember')->getMock();


        $extMember     = $this->objFromFixture("ExtMember", "ext_member");
        Injector::inst()->registerService($MockExtMember, 'ExtMember');
        $extMemberNull = $this->objFromFixture("ExtMember", "ext_member");


        $this->assertEquals("ext@email.com", $extMember->Email);
        $this->assertNull($extMemberNull->Email);

    }
}
```

What happened to the `$extMemberNull` object? Why do all get calls return null after I register the DataObject as a service? This is a massive road block in terms of testability

Comment: Isnt that normal behaviour for a mocked class? this is "By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a dummy implementation that just returns null (without calling the original method)." from https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: Is there any reason to use a mock object over a real object instance? In my experience, Mock objects work best for services you don't have control over, but are really not a good substitute for testing SilverStripe DataObjects.

Comment: This mocking won't help you, if you want to avoid calls to the database. When you define $fixture_file, the database becomes required and all data from fixture files are stored in the database. `objFromFixture` is used in place of `byID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a property on a DataObject (`$extMember->Email`) it is handled by magic method __get() and results in calls of either:

- $extMember->getEmail();
- $extMember->getField('Email');

Since you try to use mock object without configuration, these methods return `NULL`

Comment: Yea i noticed that yesterday... gonna try separate as much logic from the DataObjects into other services as I can